# MATLAB : bar graph_ modify parameters on axis

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I have a bar graph with 2 different data (each with a different color as you can see on the picture). I would like to move the x-axis so it crosses at y=-100 (for example). So if a data = -40, I would like to have a bar from -100 to -40.

An other question : is it possible to write each value of the x-axis vertically (because with all the values, we can't see anything).

The last question : is it possible to have 2 different scales for the x_axis ?

[image]

Thank you in advance,

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to get you going. Everything is commented so that should be easy to follow:

```
clear
clc
close all

%// Generate dummy data
y = -90*rand(1,20);
NumY = numel(y);

HalfData = round(NumY/2);

%// Loop to color half in pink and half in blue
hold all
for k = 1:NumY

    hBar = bar(k,y(k));

    if k <= HalfData
        set(hBar,'FaceColor',[1 0 1])

    else
        set(hBar,'FaceColor',[0 0 1])

    end
end
hold off

%// Get xtick labels and position for future use
xtLabels = cellstr(get(gca,'XTickLabel')).';
xtPos = get(gca,'XTick');

%// Change baseline value
set(hBar,'BaseValue',-40)

%// Get baseline to change its properties if you want
hBaseL = get(hBar,'Baseline');

set(hBaseL,'LineStyle','--','Color','k','LineWidth',3)

%// Adjust axis limits. Remove labels to place them vertically
set(gca,'XLim',[0 NumY],'XTickLabel',{''})

%// Get correct position for xlabel text
YLimPoArrays = min(get(gca,'YLim'));

YLimPoArrays = repmat(YLimPoArrays,numel(xtPos),1);

%// Place text positioned vertically with a small y offset
text(xtPos,YLimPoArrays-3,xtLabels,'HorizontalAlignment','center','Rotation',90,'FontSize',15)
```

And the output:

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great! If that helped can you mark the answer as accepted please? (Green checkmark beside it). Thanks!